# iOS Push Notifications to a topic

Tags: java, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have an Ionic app (client), with a Java 8 backend (server), and I have set up push notifications.

**client**

```
        let topics: string[] = [this.personModelLoggedIn.uid];
        const options: PushOptions = {
          android: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            sound: "true",
            vibrate: "true",
            topics: topics
          },
          ios: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: "true",
            topics: topics
          },
          windows: {}
        };
```

For `Android`, I can receive notifications, send from the following:

**server**

```
private String sendAndroidPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    String pushMessage = null;
    if (device_token != null && !device_token.equals("null")) {
        pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"message\":\"" + message + "\"},\"to\":\""
                + device_token + "\"}";
    } else {
        pushMessage = "{\"data\":{\"title\":\"" + title + "\",\"message\":\"" + message + "\"},\"to\": \"/topics/"
                + topics + "\"}";
    }
    // Create connection to send FCM Message request.
    URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + SERVER_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    // Send FCM message content.
    OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(pushMessage.getBytes());

    return "Android Push Notification: " + conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage() + " - " + pushMessage;
}
```

**Problem**

I have the following code for `iOS`, but the client does not receive the push notifications.

```
/**
 * import com.notnoop.apns.APNS; import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;
 * https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns.
 */
private String sendIOSPushNotification(String device_token, String topics, String title, String message)
        throws Exception {
    ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert(PATH_TO_P12_CERT, CERT_PASSWORD).withSandboxDestination()
            .build();

    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
            // .customFields(map)
            .alertBody(title + " " + message).sound("default").build();

    service.push(Utilities.encodeHex(topics.getBytes()), payload);
    return "iOS Push Notification: " + title + " " + message;
}
```

If you look at the `com.notnoop.apns` api, it is supposed to push to a `device token`, however, I need it to rather push to a `uid`. I have implemented the above code to push to a `uid`, but it doesn't work.

**Question**

Id it possible for the `com.notnoop.apns` api to push notifications to a topic? Otherwise, is there another api that will be able to do this?

If neither is possible, should the client rather listen on the `device token`? But the problem here is, that the sender of the push notification does not know the receivers `device token`. The sender does know the receivers `uid` though.

Thanks